# Custom resolve of registered type on runtime in multi-tenant architecture with Autofac

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autofac, multi-tenant

I'm facing a problem where I need to implement some sort of a custom resolver for registered types in Autofac.

My setup looks like this:

I have a multi tenant architecture where I have several databases (one per tenant, all sharing the same schema). One application needs to traverse all databases to collect data.

I've come up with an idea to use autofac to register the DbContext, but when resolving the `IEnumerable<DbContext>` I need a way to resolve these in runtime by some custom code to figure out the connection strings for each context from another database.

I'll try to make it clearer with some pseudo-code:

```
private void Configure()
        {
            _container.RegisterType<DbContext>()
                .ResolveBy(() =>  /*some custom code to resolve all DbContext based on the number of tenants*/);
        }

        public class MultiContextService
        {
            private readonly IEnumerable<DbContext> _dbContexts;

            public MultiContextService(IEnumerable<DbContext> dbContexts )
            {
                _dbContexts = dbContexts;
            }

            public void SomeMethod()
            {
                foreach (var context in _dbContexts)
                {
                   //do something to each context... 
                }   
            }
        }
```

**Note** that tenants can be added during runtime and should be able to be resolved without the instance needs to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem becomes much easier if *you don't inject the DbContext at all*. Instead provide application code with an abstraction that allows you to retrieve the DbContext at runtime. For instance:

```
public interface IContextProvider {
    IEnumerable<DbContext> Contexts { get; }
}
```

Now you move the problem of collecting the right set of DbContexts to the `IContextProvider` implementation, but this will be considerably easier.

If possible, try to hide the fact that you have a list of `DbContext` instances behind an abstraction, in such way that you don't have to litter your application code with `foreach (var context in contexts)` methods.

Comment: I see your point.  My example is somewhat simplified to get the question understandable. The fact is that my current architecture uses the repository and unit of work pattern. Each repository gets injected with an unitOfWork and each unitOfWork has an abstraction of DbContext injected. Therefore I tried to continue with this solution. That would need me to create up a list of repositories as well for each context.

Answer (score 0):

If you want runtime behaviour then you can work with the Assembly registrar.  Something like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Autofac;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // customise your assembly loader for runtime behaviour
            containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(DbContext))
                .As<DbContext>().OnPreparing(eventArgs =>
                {
                    // depending on which context you are activating you can do use somekind of convention to get the correct connection string
                });


            containerBuilder.RegisterType<MultiContextService>();
            var container = containerBuilder.Build();

            var mcs = container.Resolve<MultiContextService>();

        }
    }

    internal class MultiContextService
    {
        public MultiContextService(IEnumerable<DbContext> allContexts)
        {
            // all contexts are resolved here
        }
    }

    internal abstract class DbContext
    {
    }

    internal class DbContext1 : DbContext
    {

    }

    internal class DbContext2 : DbContext
    {

    }
}
```

Will that work?